# Correct notation for a versor

Tags: notation

I am writing an engineering thesis and I am in doubt about the correct notation for versors.

Is it a [circunflex accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex), an [anticircunflex/caron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron) accent or a [breve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breve)?

I appreciate any comments you might have.

Comment: I don't know that there is a standard notation.  Here is the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor) on versors, if that helps.  I think any notation is acceptable so long as you define it clearly,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of mathematical notation is clear communication.  Insofar as there is "correct" notation and "incorrect" notation, it comes down to whether or not the notation used achieves this goal of clear communication.  There are typically two important ways of ensuring that your notation is clear:

1. **Use standard notation when available.**  If one knows that there is standard notation for an object or idea, use that notation.  Using non-standard notation is likely to cause confusion, as mathematicians have grown used to certain symbols and definitions.  Changing things up is akin to using non-standard spelling—you can probably make yourself understood, but you are going to make it hard on your readers, so you probably shouldn't.

   For example, $\mathbb{N}$ is almost always used to denote the set of natural numbers, $|\cdot |$ typically denotes the absolute value of a real or complex number, and $f'$ generally denotes the derivative of a single-variable function $f$.  Using these notations is unlikely to ever cause confusion.
2. **Clearly define the notation being used.** If one is not aware of standard notation, or if there is no standard notation, or if standard notation is going to cause confusion, then one has to introduce new notation.  The key here is to very clearly define the notation before using it.

For versors, I am not aware of any standard notation.  Of course, I didn't know what a versor was until I looked it up on Wikipedia (and I still don't know if this question is about unit quaternions or unit vectors more generally).  Because I am not familiar with any standard notation, I would be comfortable introducing my own notation.  Since a "hat" over a letter often denotes a unit vector, I like the following:

> **Definition:**  A *versor* is a vector (or quaternion) of unit length.  Versors are distinguished from other vectors by a "hat".  For example, given a vector $v$, the versor in the direction of $v$, denoted by $\hat{v}$, is the versor
> $$ \hat{v} = \frac{ v }{ | v | }, $$
> where $|v|$ denotes the magnitude (norm, length, whatever) of $v$.

In $\LaTeX$, this is typeset as `$\hat{v}$`, which produces a circumflex.

Comment: I agree that a 'hat' is the most common notation of a normalized vector, e.g. $\hat x,\ \hat y,\ \hat z,\ \hat v, \ldots$

Comment: Xander, thank you for your very clear reply. Indeedn I was talking about vectors of unitary length. Since I'm not a matematician I figured this was the place to ask. I agree with you on everything, except that I've seen versors denoted with an inverted hat more often than with a hat.

Comment: @tron_ccp I made no claim about the relative frequency; all I said was that a hat *often* denotes a unit vector.  While I've never seen a breve or caron used for a unit vector, I have no doubt that someone uses it, and that it is very common in certain fields of study or regions of the world. ;)